# Java FX On IDE, fxml file don't open with Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

When I try open fxml with SceneBuilder on IDE I have error (Make sure that the chosen valid FXML ducument):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\RafaĹ‚\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaFXApplication2\src\javafxapplication2\FXMLDocument.fxml (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.readContentFromURL(FXOMDocument.java:389)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:385)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:665)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp$1.invalidated(SceneBuilderApp.java:517)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:136)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:103)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.UserLibrary.lambda$updateFirstExplorationCompleted$6(UserLibrary.java:352)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I set in IDE options path to Scene Builder

- on NetBeans I can't chose SB.exe ,  so I set folder C:\Program Files\SceneBuilder
- on Eclipse I set SB.exe
- on Windows SB.exe works

Please help me. What should I do to start work with SceneBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug, the solution is

1. For the first time, open scene builder outside your IDE
2. Click **File** - **Open** - **YourFXMLFilename.fxml**
3. Try open another FXML file in inside your IDE

Comment: Thanks but on IDE still not work. When I open fxml by Scene Builder outside IDE everything is OK. Another fxml not work on IDE